# in ios 8 simulator can work for email sending properly

Tags: xcode-6.2, ios8.2

i am sending the email by using MessageUI Framework.It get crash log.
    Exception Type:Sigabrt and code:ox000000000000 0x000000000000.and abort() called.I tried to login into the simulator on my gmail it doesnt appear.

```
some friends on stackoverflow wrote that ios 8 simulator doesnt support the mfmailcomposeviewcontroller in on device it is working.

can you please give proper answer.
thanks for adavance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xcode 6 Simulator cannot run Email Sharing,But in Iphone it is working.I tested in Device.Dont Worry about Abort() called method.